# Django Model Choices

Tags: django, django-south

I've been stumped by how to make choices within my models for hours.

So far I've been having issues with my approved field in the model. I want approved to be 1 of the 3 choices,but what I appear to get is a tuple of all three choices. Within './manage.py shell', I get

```
>>> listing.objects.all()[0].approved
((u'1', u'Awaiting'), (u'2', u'No'), (u'3', u'Yes'))
```

My Model:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class directory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length="50")

class listing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length="50")
    directory = models.ForeignKey(directory)
    birthday = models.DateField()
    state = models.CharField(max_length="2") 
    owner = models.CharField(max_length="50")
    approved = (
        (u'1', u'Awaiting'),
        (u'2', u'No'),
        (u'3', u'Yes'),
    )
```

Also side question: But whenever I make model changes and try to migrate schemas with South my commandline will freeze up and won't ever finish migrating schemas. Any possible suggestions for why it freezes? It can detect changes but wont ever finish implementing them. Because it never finishes, I cant access my model through the admin panel anymore when I click on the model to make changes, I can never load the page.

```
The order in which I run the commands are
    ./manage.py convert_to_south myapp
    ./manage.py schemamigration southtut --auto
    ./manage.py migrate southtut ( never progresses on this command after the first few lines appear)
```

Comment: You should probably turn the second part into it's own question to keep things on-topic, rather than making it a "side question".

Comment: I suggest you try the South migration again once you've fixed the model. Also, change "myapp" above to "southtut" because other people like me will pick up on it wonder whether that's part of the problem. Also, make the class names CapWords. Maybe read the PEP-8 guidelines on Python if you've not already: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`approved` as you have it isn't a field, it's simply a class attribute containing the three choices. The choices need to be an attribute of an actual field:

```
APPROVAL_CHOICES = (
    (u'1', u'Awaiting'),
    (u'2', u'No'),
    (u'3', u'Yes'),
)
approved = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=APPROVAL_CHOICES)
```

Comment: Can this be possible if my field datatype is integer instead of CharField?

Comment: Thanks Daniel, Apology, I am very new to Django. The following code worked for me and django admin UI shows me a dropdown now.
ACTIVE = 0
INACTIVE = 1
STATUS = (
    (ACTIVE, 'active'),
    (INACTIVE, 'inactive'),
)

class TemplateAddon(models.Model):
  status =  models.IntegerField(default=0, choices=STATUS)