# I want that Django model field can have only two possible values

Tags: django

```
class Proposta(models.Model):
     descrizione = models.TextField()
     titolo = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     richiedibile = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     inRichiesta = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     archiviata = models.BooleanField(default=False)

     # tesi or AP
     tipologia = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I want that the 'tipologia' field can have only two possible value: 'tesi' or 'AP'. In other words I want the field looks like a list in which user can  choose the value he want.

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025733/django-model-choices

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#choices) argument in your Charfield:

```
TIPOLOGIA_CHOICES = [
    ("tesi", "tesi"),
    ("AP", "AP"),
]

class Proposta(models.Model):
    ...
    tipologia = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=TIPOLOGIA_CHOICES)
```

Comment: also remember to add a default or make it nullable